# Negative health effects of loneliness?

Tags: cognitive-science, psychologist-psychology, behavior, environmental-psychology

Feeling lonely seems like a natural phenomena, but are there negative health consequences of specifically feeling lonely? What exactly happens in the brain to make a person feel lonely?

And if it has negative conseuqences, what actions should one take to amend these negative effects? I assume one would be to interact with people more, but given limited time, energy, and commitment abilities, I wonder if other techniques exist.

Comment: Do you have a prepared answer?

Comment: Eh I might. Most of the questions I pose are ones in which I'm interested in other people's insights. If no one provides a response for a while and if I have time, I'll answer it myself though. Maybe it'll help improve peoples' lifestyles if we find some solutions.